# Accumulating strategic resources in Civ5

Tags: civilization-modding

I want to change the way Civ5 handles resources.

In Civ5 if you have 8 Iron sites worked then you have 8 Iron resource in total. If you build 1 swordsman you now have 7 Iron resource.

What I want to do is change resources so that an Iron mine produces so many Iron per turn and that amount accumulates like gold or faith does. Then when you build a swordsman, it reduces the total accumulated resources.

As of yet I've found no other mods that attempt this and I have not quite narrowed down where the params would be stored for this; it very well might be something I simply am not capable of changing through XML and SQL editing. My modding has been isolated to simple changes to those types of files.

Comment: Assume you're talking to a reader who is intimately familiar with Civilization V modding, but has never played Civilization 6's Gathering Storm expansion. Ensure your question contains all the information they would need to understand in detail the changes you want to make to Civ V. It's also helpful to include what you've found from your research on the topic so far, and what you've tried / what the results of those experiments have been. It's often faster to get an answer that nudges a non-working attempt into a working one, than to have volunteer invent a complete solution from scratch.

Comment: This is more of a "Can it be done?" question; I have yet to find a clear way looking through the SQL and XML files. I'm looking for more of a point me in the right direction than an actual answer. I have read a number of mod descriptions and forums and so far have not found anyone who has tried.

Comment: Unfortunately that's kind of the problem with modding: it's often not clear whether something is even possible until you've put in the elbow grease to actually DO that specific thing. So if you can't find someone who's already done it, then someone would have to make an attempt at implementing this whole mod before they could even point you in the right direction with reasonable confidence that they're not leading you astray. That's a lot to ask of an unpaid volunteer. So you might have to do quite a lot of independent exploration and experimentation to make your start here.

Comment: I see where you are coming from but I have to disagree. I never tried to build a house out of cheese, because my knowledge and experience tells me it isn't going to work; I don't have to build a house out of cheese to determine this. A less silly example would be I would never try to use NAD83 CSRS coordinates in ATS77 because I know those two spatial dataframe have different datums. That said, someone with knowledge could still point me to the files that handle that aspect.